# Cannot specify a comparer in Contains method of an array in C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

In C#, I can specify a comparer in the Contains method of an array.  That is, the following is working well.

```
((ICollection<string>)aryStr).Contains(str, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

However, in C++/CLI, I ***cannot*** specify a comparer in the Contains method of an array, and the following is ***invalid***.

```
((ICollection<String^>^)aryStr)->Contains(val, StringComparer::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

In C++/CLI, only the following is valid.

```
((ICollection<String^>^)aryStr)->Contains(val)
```

Any comment?

Comment: My comment is that you should understand the difference between C++ and C++/CLI :-) Have adjusted your question to suit.

Comment: I don't think c++cli supports extension methods the same way as C#... Someone will confirm...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, while ability in specifying comparer is provided by extension methods which are not supported in C++/CLI, any suggestion for the case?

Comment: Extension methods are just static methods - you can call them directly. c++/cli is not a language I know well enough to give you correct syntax but should be something like `Enumerable::Contains((ICollection<string>)aryStr,val, StringComparer::OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, **Enumerable::Contains((ICollection<String^>^)aryStr, val, StringComparer::OrdinalIgnoreCase)** is working well.  Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

For C++/CLI, it may be written as follows.

```
Enumerable::Contains((ICollection<String^>^)aryStr, val, StringComparer::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```